# Return an Array from an Async call, then additional Async calls for each element of the array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, architecture, synchronous

I'm writing an application in javascript where I make a CORS request to the server to grab a data array.

Then, for each item in the array, I need to make another CORS call to get additional info on that element.

I originally thought I could return values from my CORS request like:

```
data = getData(param);
```

But apparently you can't mix synchronous and asynchronous code.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show a more complete code example that demonstrates how you're trying to "mix synchronous and asynchronous code"?

Answer (score 1):

Promises. Here's how you might use them using your requirements, and a `setTimeout` to mimic an AJAX request.

`getData` returns a new promise. In this case if the function is called with no params an array is sent back after a second (your first request). If a param is passed into the function `100` is added to the param before resolving - the later requests.

```
function getData(param) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (param) {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(param + 100), 500);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => resolve([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 1000)
    }
  });
}
```

Call `getData` without a param and `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is returned. `then` we map over the array elements and return *new* promises for each of them. `then` we use `Promise.all` to resolve those promises and `then` we output the final array `[101, 102, 103, 104, 105]`.

```
getData()
  .then((arr) => arr.map(el => getData(el)))
  .then(arr => Promise.all(arr))
  .then(arr => console.log(arr));
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7bL7acsj/2/)

So you can see that you can run one AJAX request and then run more based on the result of the value that's returned until all requests have been made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async.series. checkout https://github.com/caolan/async . Very good library to solve problem like this -  process an array data asynchronously(My favourite).

**Or**

You can use js promise from https://www.promisejs.org/

**Or** play with callbacks... like below

**Note:** Below functions are indicative functions just to show how you can approach the problem as you haven't shared any code. Change them accordingly. Also there might be syntactical/spell error as the code is written directly here.

```
function ajaxRequester(method,uri, data, onSuccess, onError){ // you can make this function as per requirement.
   $.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: uri,
    data: data
    success: function(response){
     onSuccess(response);
    }
   });
}
function yourFunction(){
 ajaxRequester('GET',urlOf1stRequest,dataToSend,function(resp){
    // assuming resp is the array received from server. we'll start with 0th element 
  processArray(0,resp, function(){
   // do your final stuff
  });
 });
}

function processArray(index, arr, onComplete){
 if(index < arr.lenght){
  var objToProcess = arr[index]; // get your data to process
  ajaxRequester(yourMethod,obj.url, obj.data, function(resp){
   // do work with your response variable resp
    processArray(++index, arr); // process next element of array after completion of current
  });

 } else {
  onComplete(); // all elements are processed call final callback
 }
}
```