# How to make multiple AJAX requests and use all results from each request when available?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I am trying to make two or more separate AJAX requests simultaneously or in parallel.
When all requests are finished and returned data for all AJAX requests, I want to call a function with all of the data at once.

### So far:

1. Successfully making the separate AJAX requests and gathering data separately.
2. (Successfully?) make 2 parallel AJAX requests but when I try to access all of the data at once or send all the data to a function I get undefined:

### I have tried:

*Tried using the following style of AJAX:

```
function Ajax(handleData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,  
        type: 'POST',
        data: data_ajax,
        success:function(data) {
            handleData(data);
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
}
Ajax(function(output){
    response_parsed = JSON.parse(output);
    do stuff like assign to global var
}
```

* Tried using the following style of AJAX:

```
get_array = (function(){
      var response_parsed;
      $.ajax({
         url: url,  
         type: 'POST',
         data: data_ajax,
         success:function(data) {
            response_parsed = JSON.parse(data);
         },
         error: function(e){
            console.log(e.message);
         },
      });
      return {getData : function()
      {
         if(response_parsed) return response_parsed;
      }};
   })();
```

where trying `get_array.getData` doesnt work out but `get_array` has the data in a `closure`?

[image]

How can I access the closure stuff?

---

So basically, I have a function that calls the separate AJAX requests (which are separate functions) and then on success its supposed to either assign that data to a global var or send that data off to get processed and compiled:

I tried assigning the response data to a global variable (I know everyone hates on global var) but I still couldnt use or pass that information to a function (undefined):

```
function start(){
    call_ajax1();
    call_ajax2();
    compile_data(data_array_from_request1, data_array_from_request2);
}
```

I tried `return`ing the data on success.

```
function start(){
    data_array_from_request1 = call_ajax1();
    data_array_from_request2 = call_ajax2();
    compile_data(data_array_from_request1, data_array_from_request2);
}
```

---

Need some guidance...
Do I need to chain successes together somehow?

I found jQuery.when() recently but unsure if its what I am looking for.

Please let me know how to improve this question.

Comment: Try `Promise.all` or `$.when` in jQuery.

Comment: [My answer to a recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776114/return-an-array-from-an-async-call-then-additional-async-calls-for-each-element/36776686#36776686) might help.

Comment: Try defining a global scope empty object and whenever Ajax returns data then assign to it as `myobj.ajax1 = data` and do same thing in other call as well.

Comment: @kakurala i tried that with a global array... but not object.

Comment: @kakurala Polluting the global scope that way is not only unnecessary, it's a bad idea. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted

Comment: @kakurala no, this is not the way to go. Use `Promise.all` or `Promise.spread` e.g. in bluebird - or in almost any promise framework.

Comment: Yes understood, but it is sort of easy solution, since terminologies like promise ,differed are quite confusing for newbies until unless they understand the beauty of it. And if you use global scope gently without pouring all the stuff in there, its fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're mentioning jQuery. It can easily be solved as such:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax('http://example1.com'),
    $.ajax('http://example2.com')
)
.then(function(response1, response2) {
    console.log(response1);
    console.log(response2);
})
.fail(function(err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong', err);
});
```

`$.ajax('http://example1.com')` can of course be more advanced ajax calls, such as the one in your original post:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data_ajax
    }),
    $.ajax({
        url: url2,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data_ajax
    })
)
.then(...)
```

Also see [the jQuery documentation on `.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) which also explains how to handle errors.

Comment: ill give it a try!

Comment: can I use functions that initiate the ajax requests in the $.when?
do I have to return the actual $.ajax from the function to make that work?

Comment: I don't really understand your question but `$.when` will take any `promise`. The `ajax` method returns a promise. If you want to do e.g. `function something() { return $.ajax('http://www.example.com'); }` and then `$.when(something)` that's perfectly fine.

Comment: You might want to read an introduction to promises, e.g. https://davidwalsh.name/promises Just be aware: jQuery has its own non standard compliant implementation of Promises so you want to take a look at the jQuery documentation once you get a hang of it.